# Point value applied to choice from IF equation

Tags: excel

I'll try to do my best to explain the situation and what I'm working with.

I am working on creating a quiz within Excel 2010 and am trying to create a function that references another by assigning a point value when either Correct or Incorrect is generated by an existing formula. This is the formula I'm using right now for the quiz:

=IF(C4=Answers!B5,"Correct!","Incorrect")

I want to assign "1" to Correct and "0" to Incorrect and have that number add to a cell on a different sheet.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Try looking up the COUNTIF() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function suggested by @Dave: If the answers are in ColumnC, your formulae in ColumnE and the correct answers in ColumnB of Sheet `Answers` then the `Correct!` results may be counted in the same sheet as the formula with:

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,"Correct!")
```